# Complex domain model based on companies and not users

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, domain-model

I have a few different types of companies that can access my web application e.g

Different types of Companies:

Client
Supplier
Agent

Each have their own table in the database, linked to the main table Company which stores all common data e.g. Address, Tel, Email, TypeOfCompany with a FK to the relevant table (Client etc.)...

What is the best way to handle this OO throughout my app?

I currently do something like:

```
public class CompanyDTO
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Address Address {get;set;}
  public string Type {get;set;} //type of company
  //etc...
}
```

then inherit from that class and add aditional properties e.g.

```
public class ClientDTO : CompanyDTO
{
 public string Key {get;set;}
 public Address Billing {get;set;}
}
```

However I am finding it problematic at times for example

1. **Supplier user** wants to access: AllCompanies, - show a list of all companies
2. Then the **user from the Supplier Company** wants to view a **specific** companies detail, now if it is a client I will need to show ClientDTO or SupplierDTO? In this instance I want to show that specific companies **Full details**

What would be the best way to handle this?

e.g. `GetCompanyByID(int companyid);` or `GetClientByID(int clientid);` What type of object should I return in both instances, presuming I want Client details in both instances...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny how databases don't understand OO practices like derivation, aggregation, and encapsulation.  It is an unfortunate failing but still only a part of what is overall referred to as "[database impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)".

What your attempting to do is common enough there are several solutions...

Firstly there is the choice of the data model stored.  There are basically three possibilities.

1. Split the tables as you have done.
2. Declare all fields for all derived types in the same table.
3. Use a blob field (json/xml/whatever) to house the uncommon fields.

Secondly there is the issue you bring up, requesting the data from the database.  Primarily this is centered around the request of a list of the 'common' base type and how to then access the uncommon fields that they don't share.  Again there are several possibilities.

1. When listing the base type only those common fields are returned.  Then subsequent queries are issued one-off to lazy load the other fields.
2. When listing the base type all other tables needed are also outer joined to the main table to ensure all fields are available to instantiate the object model fully.
3. When listing the base type, multiple result sets are returned, one for each 'sub type' table that may be needed for the results.  The client then pieces the records together building up the object model until it is complete.

Not an exhaustive list, but a start.  Personally I prefer to avoid data models like the one you describe for this reason.  Essentially my preference is to have the data model define the union of all fields (model #2), and then use a business layer to determine what properties are exposed, validated, required, etc.  I have also used model #3 above, using blob fields for multiple values, and it works well enough also depending upon need.  The only downside to model #3 over #2 is that you will not be able to query or sort on those fields.  Ultimately either approach still needs the business logic layer involved to know what data to expose.

Remember databases are stupid, treat them as such and you will get along well.  (note: this advice does not work on people, just databases)

Comment: A good answer, though I personally would never suggest #3 - it violates principles of normalisation and doesn't allow querying or sorting as you say, that's a big decision to concede up front. I'm with you on option #2.

Comment: These fields must be queryable for me personally, hence why they have their own field inside the table...

Comment: Violating principles of normalization is my every day task.  I've grown so adept at it that now I fail to even consider how many violations just one of my tables has much less my entire schema.  Yet while others are complaining about 150 line SQL statements and 25-table joins, my application continues to run fast and scale well.  IMHO, normalization is the worst thing in the world to teach a fledgling programmer.  BTW, I've been writing database applications since '97 and it took me 8 or 9 years to figure out that normalization sux.

Comment: *normalization is the worst thing in the world to teach a fledgling programmer* - nah, there are worse things. I'd rather start them off on the right track - because normalisation is on balance a good thing - and then illustrate cases where denormalised schemas are more appropriate as you encounter them.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to access: AllCompanies, - show a list of all companies

When you want a list of companies, aren't you asking for the general details that instances of `CompanyDTO` describe? Maybe your data access (service, repository, etc) could look like:

```
public class CompanyRepository : ICompanyRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<CompanyDTO> GetCompanies()
    {
        // get companies and map them to CompanyDTO objects as necessary
    }
}
```

Then you asked (well, there is a question mark)

> Then I want to view a specific companies detail, now if it is a client I will need to show ClientDTO or SupplierDTO?

I'm assuming this would be a separate view, or at least broken down into a separate partial views. But, you could use [Display Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) to describe your child types of companies since you've describes an inheritance above.

I will pretend you showed us your controller and it looks like this:

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        CompanyRepository repo = new CompanyRepository();
        return View(repo.GetCompanyById(id));
    }
}
```

Then, add a strongly-typed view named `Details`, that inherits a `CompanyDTO` object, and add a call to `Html.DisplayForModel()`:

```
<%--some scaffolded code ommitted for brevity--%>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <%= Html.DisplayForModel() %>

</asp:Content>
```

Then, here's where display templates come in. **Add a folder**:

```
~/Views/Company/DisplayTemplates
```

Then add to that folder **3 strongly-typed**, *partial* views--one for each child type. Visual Studio will help you with this:

1. Right-click the `DisplayTemplates` folder --> Add View...
2. Name it "ClientDTO" (this is important)
3. tick "Create a partial view"
4. tick "Create a strongly-typed view"
5. Select the `ClientDTO` class
6. Select `Details` for view content (this will give you some auto generated markup)
7. Click Add

Repeat this process for other child types and the correct template will be rendered based on the *child* type of the model passed to your Details view.

Comment: David - why did you answer the question with respect to MVC? This isn't a criticism, I'm just interested in what element of the question gave you that suggestion..

Comment: @MalcomTucker Hmmm...I swear there was a asp.net-mvc-2 tag on this question.

Comment: Ahh ok, thought I'd missed something! Probably the right decision to remove it, it doesn't really necessitate a *UI* solution (IMO)

Comment: @Haroon Glad to hear it--if I can elaborate or review in any way let me know